# Filter Array by "isComplete"

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have two data sets "ProjectItem" and "TaskItem", and a project can have many tasks. I want to filter tasks by "isComplete" in the project they belong to.

In my ProjectItem+CoreDataProperties file I have the following:

```
extension ProjectItem {

    @NSManaged public var projectColor: String
    @NSManaged public var projectId: UUID
    @NSManaged public var projectTitle: String
    @NSManaged public var projectDateCreated: Date
    @NSManaged public var isFavorite: Bool
    @NSManaged public var task: NSSet
    
    public var taskArray: [TaskItem] {
        let set = task as? Set<TaskItem> ?? []
        -- How can I filter for "isComplete" here? -- 
    }
}
```

And TaskItem+CoreDataProperties looks like this:

```
extension TaskItem {

    @NSManaged public var completedDate: Date
    @NSManaged public var completeIcon: String
    @NSManaged public var createdDate: Date
    @NSManaged public var dueDate: Date
    @NSManaged public var id: UUID
    @NSManaged public var isComplete: Bool
    @NSManaged public var notes: String
    @NSManaged public var priority: String
    @NSManaged public var title: String
    @NSManaged public var project: ProjectItem?
}
```

How can I modify the array in the first code snippet to show only tasks where "isComplete" = true?

Many thanks!

Comment: What does "match as "isComplete"" mean? Match what?

Comment: Sorry, I clarified my question

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to define the Coredata managed property with dynamic `NSSet` any more. You could as well use, generic set with the `Element` type and Core data is able to infer the type from underlying store. So, your class could be changed to something like this,

```
extension ProjectItem {

    @NSManaged public var projectColor: String
    @NSManaged public var projectId: UUID
    @NSManaged public var projectTitle: String
    @NSManaged public var projectDateCreated: Date
    @NSManaged public var isFavorite: Bool
    // Notice this 
    @NSManaged public var task: Set<TaskItem>   
}
```

So, for completed task items, you can simply use filter on `Set` if you want.

```
extension ProjectItem {

  var completedItems: Set<TaskItem> {
    return task.filter(\.isComplete)  // for 5.2 and above
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you @Sandeep! However, I get this error on my foreach loop - "Referencing initializer 'init(_:id:content:)' on 'ForEach' requires that 'Set<TaskItem>' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'"

`ForEach(projectItem.completedItems id: \.self) { taskItem in`

Comment: Hmm, you can convert set to Array using Array(task.filter(\.isComplete)) and convert the return type of above computed variable to be Array<TaskItem>. That could likely fix the issue

Comment: How could I modify your original return statement to show 'isComplete' false items? @Sandeep?

Comment: What do you mean? Your `isComplete` is already `Bool` type?

Answer (score 1):

It is more optimal to create explicit fetch request and allow CoreData to filter `isCompleted` tasks by predicate, like

```
struct TaskView: View {

    var tasksRequest : FetchRequest<TaskItem>
    var tasks : FetchedResults<TaskItem>{tasksRequest.wrappedValue}

    init(){
        self.tasksRequest = FetchRequest(entity: TaskItem.entity(), sortDescriptors: [], 
            predicate: NSPredicate(format: "isComplete == YES"))
    }

    // ... other code
```

Comment: Thanks! Will this fetch tasks that belong to a project? Or is this for all existing tasks?

Comment: @DaleHumphries, if you need more conditions just construct combined predicate